# Parse string in right format with javascript

Tags: javascript, date-parsing

I have a string which is allways in this format: 7 May 2012 or 17 May 2012
My goal is to parse this string and get the date in this format: yyyy-mm-dd

So, my example 7 May 2012 will become 2012-05-07 and 17 May 2012 will become 2012-05-17

I have tryed with

```
Date.parse("7 May 2012", "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

but the result is:

```
Sun May 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `Date.parse` only takes one parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you got that `Date.parse` call, JavaScript's `Date.parse` has no second argument.

To do this, you'll need to parse the string yourself, or use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) or similar to do it for you. If you want to parse it yourself, you'll probably want a regular expression and a lookup table (for the month names). The regex would be along these lines:

```
var parts = /^\s*(\d+)\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+(\d+)\s*$/.exec(str);
```

...where you'd end up with `parts[0]` being the day, `parts[1]` the month name, and `parts[2]` the year. Then just convert the month to lower or upper case, and use a lookup table to map month name to month number, something along these lines:

```
var months = {
    "jan": 0,
    "january": 0,
    "feb": 1,
    "february": 1,
    "may": 4,
    // ...
    "dec": 11,
    "december": 11
};
var parts = /^\s*(\d+)\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+(\d+)\s*$/.exec(str);
var dt;
if (parts) {
    parts[2] = months[parts[2].toLowerCase()];
    if (typeof parts[2] !== "undefined") {
        dt = new Date(parseInt(parts[3], 10),
                      parts[2],
                      parseInt(parts[1], 10));
    }
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/osozul) | [source](http://jsbin.com/osozul/edit)

Then you can format the resulting `Date` object. (Again, there are libs to help there.)

Or, of course, never actually make a `Date` and just format directly from `parts`.

Comment: Hi an thank you for the answer, but parse is always undefined for me.

Comment: @Ana: Sorry, I forgot that index 0 is the *overall* string match ("7 May 2012"), followed by the capture groups. So all the indexes were off by one. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder, I will try it.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) works, it just takes one parameter, and it returns a unix timestamp.

If you want a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/) object, use `new Date`.

```
var myDate = new Date("7 May 2012");
// Mon May 07 2012 00:00:00
```

You can then parse it yourself into the format you want:

```
var year = myDate.getFullYear(),
    month = myDate.getMonth() + 1, // month returns 0-11, not 1-12
    day = myDate.getDate();
var dateStr = year + '-' + (month < 10 ? 0 : '') + month + '-' + (day < 10 ? 0 : '') + day;
```

**NOTE**: `"7 May 2012"` is a non-standard date format, and may not work correctly in all browsers.

**NOTE 2**: To be 100% sure that it'll work in all browsers, I'd use a library like [`Datejs`](http://www.datejs.com/).

```
// Using Date.js
var myDate = Date.parse('7 May 2012');
var dateStr = myDate.toString('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: `var myDate = new Date("7 May 2012");` uses an unsupported, unspecified format which will may well not work reliably cross-browser. The only format in [the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) was added only for ES5, and doesn't use month names at all (for obvious reasons of locale). I'd expect the above to fail on, say, French-localized browsers (though I don't have one handy). You'd be relying on undocumented behavior in any case.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Mozilla says that `new Date` (and `Date.parse`) also support RFC 2822 dates.

Comment: @ Rocket: Mozilla doesn't define the standard (anymore). ECMA does. If they'd wanted to include RFC 2822 in the spec, they'd have done so.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That doesn't mean browsers *cough* IE *cough* actually follow the standards :-P

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I agree, I'd be careful this, it *may* not work as expected in all browsers.

Comment: Browsers are free to go beyond the standard if they like. For instance, I've tested "YYYY/dd/mm" and found it reliable all the way back to IE6 (and Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Midori, and a few others). Still undocumented, but hey. But that doesn't involve month *names*, which seems pretty dodgy to me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: When writing this answer, I was like "could I just `new Date` this?"  And, hey it worked!  I do know about standards, but it happened to work, so whatever :-)

Comment: @Rocket: It happened to work. In the brand and version of browser you were using. In your locale. This is how bugs happen, man! :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That's why I now suggested Datejs :P

Comment: @Rocket: Yeah, I used to, but it hasn't been updated in years and has bugs parsing midnight with certain formats, so I've started suggesting MomentJS instead.